# no error on sql insert, yet table has no data

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, appcelerator-mobile

i'm using sqlite in titanium mobile. i've had no problem running updates on another table, in the same db, so my connection seems to be ok. however, when i run inserts on a table, i'm not getting any data inserted and no error/exception is being thrown.  so i'm confused on what is happening. here is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE events (
gCal_uid VARCHAR,
title VARCHAR,
content VARCHAR,
location VARCHAR,
startTime VARCHAR, 
endTime VARCHAR, 
published VARCHAR,
updated VARCHAR,
eventStatus VARCHAR
);
```

here is the code. you can see the insert statement below. on the output of the variables, they all have data in them. possibly my syntax is wrong?

```
var db = Ti.Database.open('content');
Titanium.API.info(" number or results returned = " + cal.feed.entry.length);
var i;
for (i=0; i < cal.feed.entry.length; i++){
    var e = cal.feed.entry[i];

    var calUid = e.gCal$uid.value;
    var title = e.title.$t;
    var content = e.content.$t;
    var location = e.gd$where.valueString;
    var startTime = e.gd$when[0].startTime;
    var endTime =  e.gd$when[0].endTime;
    var published = e.published.$t;
    var updated = e.updated.$t;
    var eventStatus = e.gd$eventStatus.value;

    Titanium.API.info(calUid + title + content + location + startTime + endTime + published + updated + eventStatus);

    var theData = db.execute('INSERT INTO events (gCal_uid, title, content, location, startTime, endTime, published, updated, eventStatus) VALUES("'+calUid+'","'+title+'", "'+content+'", "'+location+'", "'+startTime+'", "'+endTime+'", "'+published+'", "'+updated+'", "'+eventStatus+'")');
    theData;
    Ti.API.info("rows inserted" + i);
}
Ti.API.info("closed the db");
db.close();
```

Comment: Please!!!!! Escape your values when you are preparing SQL statements!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL uses single quotes. Javascript uses either.

You want the resulting SQL to be as if you'd written

```
INSERT info foo (a,b) values ('a value', 'b value')
```

The simplest more-correct equivalent would be:

```
var theData = db.execute("INSERT INTO events (gCal_uid, title, content, location, startTime, endTime, published, updated, eventStatus) VALUES('"+calUid+"','"+title+"','"+content+"','"+location+"','"+startTime+"','"+endTime+"','"+published+"','"+updated+"','"+eventStatus+"')");
```

But you really want to use parameter substitution to avoid injection issues and quoting errors, e.g.

```
var theData = db.execute("INSERT INTO events (gCal_uid, title, content, location, startTime, endTime, published, updated, eventStatus) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", calUid, title, content, location, startTime, endTime, published, updated, eventStatus);
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL string literals are to be surrounded by single quotes, not double quotes.

```
INSERT INTO foo (a) VALUES("a");
```

is not a correct statement.

```
INSERT INTO foo (a) VALUES('a');
```

is a correct SQL statement.

Moreover you MUST ensure that what you insert is properly escaped (which you do not). You must therefore double every single single quote inside your variable before concatenating it with the rest of the SQL statement.

Comment: thanks for the response. i'm basing my example off this tutorial http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/titanium-mobile-database-driven-tables-with-sqlite-part-2/ 

i haven't had a chance to change and check my code by removing the  double quotes, but it would help if you could tell me what the difference would be for this vs their code, or what is being done. i'm still somewhat new to sql so just want to make sure i understand what your saying properly.  thanks for the help.